# Iterate through selected value of combo boxes for datediff

Tags: vb.net

I'm running into an issue with some logic and wondering if you'd be able to help me through it?

How can i iterate through the combo boxes to get the datediff function to work.

I'm trying to calculate the time difference from combo boxes, cbIn(i) vs clout(i)

```
Dim HoursBox1 As List(Of ComboBox)

Private Sub TimeSheet_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


HoursBoxIn1 = New List(Of ComboBox)(New ComboBox() {cbInW1, cbInTh1, cbInF1, cbInSat1, cbInSun1, cbInMon1, cbInTue1})
    HoursBoxOut1 = New List(Of ComboBox)(New ComboBox() {cbOutW1, cbOutTh1, cbOutF1, cbOutSat1, cbOutSun1, cbOutMon1, cbOutTue1})


End Sub





Private Sub btnCalcTimes_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalcTimes.Click


For Each cb As ComboBox In HoursBox1

         theTime = (DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, cbInW1.SelectedItem,   cbOutW1.SelectedItem) / 60)

next
     For Each cb As ComboBox In HoursBoxOut1


        Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on silvusvalentine's answer, since you are going by the minute and dividing by 60 you might want to change the type to decimal.  I assume you also want to add up the list and have some error handling in case someone doesn't select a value.

```
    times = New List(Of Decimal)
    Dim ListSum As Decimal = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To HoursBoxIn1.Count - 1

' if the item is empty add a decimal 

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(HoursBoxIn1(i).SelectedItem) Then
            times.Add(0)
        Else
            times.Add(DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, DateTime.Parse(HoursBoxIn1(i).SelectedItem), DateTime.Parse(HoursBoxOut1(i).SelectedItem)) / 60)
        End If
    Next

' get a total for the hours in the list of times

    For Each t As Decimal In times
        ListSum = ListSum + Val(t)
    Next
 Msgbox("Total of hours in the list " & ListSum)
```

Comment: Awesome!  I was stuck with a string error because not all the boxes had values.  Thanks.